# How to draw at ListView row?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-listview

I need to draw a line (like ~~~~~~) by repeating elements (like ~) within each `ListView` row. Length of the line will depend on the record in database. Line can also contain some separators (like ~~~~~=~~~~=~~~).

How should I draw it? (looks like I'll do that at `setViewValue`) 
What kind of element I should use in row xml to define the placeholder for that line? `Bitmap`?

Comment: Is it actually the character ~ you are drawing?  Why not just a TextView?

Comment: @Mayra, I'll use image instead of ~ (~ taken just as example).